# How to get memory type and manufacturer on AMD GPUs?

Tags: 20.04, gpu, amdgpu

I’m looking to find the memory type and most important the manufacturer on my AMD Vega 56 GPU.

In windows, there are lots of GUI utilities that shows this, like hwinfo or gpu-z. I’m looking for something similar in Ubuntu, be it GUI or CLI, that can show memory type (GDDR5, HBM etc) and most important the memory manufacturer (Hynix, Samsung etc).

Is there a way?

Comment: `sudo lshw -C memory`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help

```
hwinfo
```

i.e. `sudo apt install hwinfo`

My readout:

```
19: PCI 100.0: 0302 3D controller
  [Created at pci.386]
  Unique ID: VCu0.1Fp8+gl5uYB
  Parent ID: vSkL.9Fa8KHWfiT6
  SysFS ID: /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0
  SysFS BusID: 0000:01:00.0
  Hardware Class: graphics card
  Model: "Dell GeForce GT 630M"
  Vendor: pci 0x10de "nVidia Corporation"
  Device: pci 0x1140 "GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M]"
  SubVendor: pci 0x1028 "Dell"
  SubDevice: pci 0x054d "GeForce GT 630M"
  Revision: 0xff
  Memory Range: 0xd0000000-0xd0ffffff (rw,non-prefetchable)
  Memory Range: 0xa0000000-0xafffffff (ro,non-prefetchable)
  Memory Range: 0xb0000000-0xb1ffffff (ro,non-prefetchable)
  I/O Ports: 0x3000-0x307f (rw)
  Memory Range: 0xb2000000-0xb207ffff (ro,non-prefetchable)
  IRQ: 16 (291 events)
  Module Alias: "pci:v000010DEd00001140sv00001028sd0000054Dbc03sc02i00"
  Driver Info #0:
    Driver Status: nvidiafb is not active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe nvidiafb"
  Driver Info #1:
    Driver Status: nouveau is not active
    Driver Activation Cmd: "modprobe nouveau"
  Config Status: cfg=new, avail=yes, need=no, active=unknown
  Attached to: #16 (PCI bridge)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the heads up reg hwinfo for Linux. Unfortunately this doesn’t appear to show what I’m looking for! Memory size, type and manufacturer of the memory chip